# Where is the equivalent hook of `didInsertElement` for template?

Tags: ember.js

I am creating a "landing page" and there are some page logic (mainly animation and interaction) script need to be executed when the page is loaded.

I have tried to put `script` tag inside the template `hbs` directly but broccoli complains the syntax issues.

So I thought about the `didInsertElement` hook inside the component, however, there is no such hook for template.

Where can I put the JavaScript code for template without converting the existing part into component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ember 2.x the only walkaround is to use **Component**.

<del>You should check you **syntax** because I have tried this before and it works.</del>

For my knowledge, I am not aware there is an equivalent hook inside route which is similar to `didInsertElement`.

<del>You can also try `partial` helper inside the template and put your script inside another template to make is more clear.</del>

```
{{foo}}
{{partial "nav"}}
```

You can read more about partial at,

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_partial

A similar question has been ask here,

https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-2-0-2-10-trigger-script-after-ready/8948/2

and the suggestion is to use a component instead.

Comment: We had `didInsertElement` on views, but since they are gone for good you should use a component. However I recommend against `partial`. And `<script>` tags won't work with glimmer at all.

Comment: Thanks Lux for your clarification. Just want to make sure `partial` works right?

Comment: No. `partitial` won't help you here. Ping me in the slack channel @lux if you want to discuss this.

Comment: So the only option is to use component.

Comment: The only clean solution, yes.